# How to combine different counters in one line with SQL

Tags: sql, union

I have a mysql table with information about how many people logged in successfully and how many did not.

the follwing SQL query gives the correct values but in a sub optimal way.

```html
SELECT  Year(Time), 
  Month(Time), 
  DayOfMonth(Time),
  AccessType,
  Success,
  count(*) as Counter
FROM cas2015.TransactionLog 
WHERE AccessType = 1
GROUP BY  Year(Time), 
  Month(Time), 
  DayOfMonth(Time),  
  AccessType,
  Success
ORDER BY Time ASC;
```

It results in this table

```html
<table border="1">
  <tr BGCOLOR="#CCCCFF">
    <th>Year(Time)</th>
    <th>Month(Time)</th>
    <th>DayOfMonth(Time)</th>
    <th>AccessType</th>
    <th>Success</th>
    <th>Counter</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>2015</td>
    <td>10</td>
    <td>15</td>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>true</td>
    <td>29624</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>2015</td>
    <td>10</td>
    <td>15</td>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>false</td>
    <td>4449</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>2015</td>
    <td>10</td>
    <td>16</td>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>true</td>
    <td>26339</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>2015</td>
    <td>10</td>
    <td>16</td>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>false</td>
    <td>4069</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>2015</td>
    <td>10</td>
    <td>17</td>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>true</td>
    <td>15732</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>2015</td>
    <td>10</td>
    <td>17</td>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>false</td>
    <td>2508</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>2015</td>
    <td>10</td>
    <td>18</td>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>true</td>
    <td>16475</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>2015</td>
    <td>10</td>
    <td>18</td>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>false</td>
    <td>3138</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>2015</td>
    <td>10</td>
    <td>19</td>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>true</td>
    <td>29701</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>2015</td>
    <td>10</td>
    <td>19</td>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>false</td>
    <td>4785</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

It would help me much more to have positive and negative values in one single line next to each other. Ideally I could have a third column with positives dived by negatives.

Is this somehow possible?

```html
<table border="1">
  <tr BGCOLOR="#CCCCFF">
    <th>Year(Time)</th>
    <th>Month(Time)</th>
    <th>DayOfMonth(Time)</th>
    <th>Positive</th>
    <th>Negative</th>
    <th>Aggregated</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>2015</td>
    <td>10</td>
    <td>15</td>
    <td>29624</td>
    <td>4449</td>
    <td>6,6</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>2015</td>
    <td>10</td>
    <td>15</td>
    <td>26339</td>
    <td>4069</td>
    <td>6,47</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>2015</td>
    <td>10</td>
    <td>16</td>
    <td>15732</td>
    <td>2508</td>
    <td>6,27</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>2015</td>
    <td>10</td>
    <td>16</td>
    <td>16475</td>
    <td>3138</td>
    <td>5,25</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>2015</td>
    <td>10</td>
    <td>17</td>
    <td>29701</td>
    <td>4785</td>
    <td>6,21</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Thanks for your hints

Comment: Please tag dbms product used. (Some non-ANSI SQL there...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a conditional aggregate (supported by all DBMSes):

```
select dt.*,
   100 * FailCounter/SuccessCounter as FailedPercentage
from
 (   
   SELECT   Year(Time), 
        Month(Time), 
        DayOfMonth(Time),
        AccessType,
        SUM(case when Success = 'true'  then 1 else 0 end) as SuccessCounter,
        SUM(case when Success = 'false' then 1 else 0 end) as FailCounter,
   FROM cas2015.TransactionLog 
   WHERE AccessType = 1
   GROUP BY     Year(Time), 
        Month(Time), 
        DayOfMonth(Time),  
        AccessType
 ) as dt
ORDER BY 1,2,3;
```

Comment: Thank you, it works :-)
No more Copy past to excel and manually sort the columns :-)